# Check attribute of div Jquery

Tags: jquery, addclass, attr

I have some element that goes like this

```
<div class="section current" section="Email">

</div>
```

What i need is to check that section Email have class CURRENT, and do something like

```
if ($('.section').attr(section == Email).hasClass('current')){
 // Do something...
}
```

I know this is wrong syntax but i want just to simple show what i need?

Comment: The `.attr()` method is used for getting or setting an attribute, it's not used for finding an element that matches an attribute. Do you bother to read the documentation of functions before you use them, or do you just pray that they'll do what you want?

Comment: section="" is not valid html. Change it to data-section="" to make it valid and persist same behaviour.

Comment: In addition, even if it did perform searching, the argument `(section == Email)` wouldn't do what you want. That compares a variable named `section` with a variable named `Email`, and passes either `true` or `false` to the `attr` method. That's just basic Javascript syntax, nothing to do with jQuery or selectors.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **[attribute-equals-selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)**:

```
if($('.section[section="Email"]').hasClass('current')){
  //do something
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9vxgt/)**

Comment: In case you will change it to data-section="Email", just modify the selector like this: $('.section[data-section="Email"]')

Comment: @HenriHietala:section is not data attribute. so there is no need to use data.

Comment: as I commented in the question, section="" is not valid html but data-section="" is valid (html5). Of course there's no _need_ to do valid html since it works like that also.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at jQuery's attribute selector:

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

I would guess you can solve your problem with this:

```
if($(".section[section='Email]" ).hasClass("current")){/**CODE**/}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You could try like this also.

```
if ($('.section[section="Email"].current').length > 0) {

}
```

Comment: That won't work. That tests a jQuery object, which is always truthy, even if it doesn't match anything. You need `if($('.section[section="Email"].current').length > 0){`

Comment: Yes Barmar. thankyou. i just forgot to right it. Thanks anyway